# BULK INSERT data from local file to remote sql server

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I want to upload some data from a local file on my pc via SQL-manager to a sql-database on azure.

I tried

```
BULK INSERT gifts
   FROM 'c:\temp\trouwpartij.txt'  
   WITH   
      (  
         FIELDTERMINATOR =' |',  
         ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n'  
      );
```

But unfortunatly the path is pointing to a location on the sql-server, which I cannot access.

Any suggestions how to complete this simple task whitout actually developing a small application ?

Comment: do you have permissions on the database to create a table and then insert once the records are physically on the database? If so you can use the import export data utility to at least get the data onto the database and manipulate it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Kevin, you can use bcp command line utility as shown below:

```
bcp AdventureWorksLTAZ2008R2.SalesLT.Customer in 
C:\Users\user\Documents\MoveDataToSQLAzure.txt -c -U username@servername -S 
tcp:servername.database.windows.net -P password
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-load-from-csv-with-bcp) documentation may give you more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the BCP utility to load data from a local file to a SQL instance, whether it is local, Azure SQL DB, or a SQL Server in an Azure VM.